# number of page controls

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I want to know how many page controls can be used in an application??

is der any limit??

I'm using 2 pagecontrols but m not able to add more than 20 images

i have 1st page control with 18 images

and 2nd pagecontrol with 2 images.

Its not showing more than 20 images... how can i resolve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a small control that lets you know what "page" you are on when (most commonly) connected to a `UIScrollView`.

[image]

You are most likely referring to a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). Depending on what the dimensions you set each image determines how many you can fit on each "page".

If you want to fit more images on a single page, try a smaller image size.